# Jenkins error after upgrading to Xcode 8 -resource rules

Tags: jenkins, xcode8

After I upgrade to Xcode 8 from 7, the build on jenkins fails giving an error

> error: /usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules --sign"
>
> Warning: usage of --preserve-metadata with option "resource-rules" (deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10)!
> Warning: --resource-rules has been deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the Fix.
 As the warning says  --resource-rules has been deprecated.
I removed the resource-rules related script from "PackageApplication" file at location /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/

Edit the file "PackageApplication" as described below (Copy at diff location, edit and replace)

remove the lines ",resource-rules" and ", "--resource-rules=$destApp/ResourceRules.plist""